# SQLAlchemy convert field using utf8

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

How do I get the equivalent SQLAlchemy statement for this SQL query?

```
select CONVERT(blobby USING utf8) as blobby from myTable where CONVERT(blobby USING utf8)="Hello";
```

Where *blobby* is a blob type field that has to be unblobbed to a string.

I tried this

```
DBSession.query(myTable).filter(myTable.blobby.encode(utf-8)="Hello").first()
```

But doesn't work. Gives out a queer error

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with myTable.blobby has an attribute 'encode'
```

Moreover, I tried inserting into the database as follows:

```
que=myTable(blobby=str(x.blobby))
DBSession.add(que)
```

This also returns an error that says

```
(ProgrammingError) You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str). It is highly recommended that you instead just switch your application to Unicode strings.
```

This error goes away if I insert like

```
que=myTable(blobby=str(x))
```

But the inserted entries do not support foreign language values..

```
 EDIT:-
```

This is what I am trying to do :

```
I have a list of utf-8 strings. The sqlalchemy column which I am
trying to insert my string has the property "convert_unicode" set to
true. Now, I have to insert these strings into my database without
loss of data. I need to preserve my multilingual characters which
worked fine when I fetched them as utf-8 from my Mysql database.
Trouble here is inserting them into SQLite using SQLalchemy.
```

Please help. Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

So here is what I did to get rid of my encoding hell, and this error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec
can't decode byte 0xc4 in position
10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I shall explain it stepwise.

1. Use this command : `type(mydirtyunicodestring)` .
2. If it returns
        then it means you have to convert it to unicode to get
       rid of the error.(byte string!!!!)
3. Use `dirtystring.decode('utf-8')`
       or any other format to get your type to  There you
       go. No more 8 bit programming errors that go `ProgrammingError) You must not use 8-bit bytestrings unless you use a text_factory that can interpret 8-bit bytestrings (like text_factory = str).`

Comment: <nasty>Sometimes 3rd party extensions to MySQL just make things worse.</nasty>  I hope some SQLAlchemy expert comes along; it is not obvious what MySQL code is being generated; can you find the translation?